# sending a mail with attachment through excel

Tags: vba6

Sending a mail with attachment from excel in vba works most of the time, but sometimes "d.docs.live.net" is added to this attachment, with result that this attachment cannot be found or/and is unreadable. PS. Cortana doesn't work in my region. I work with Office365 and Windows 11. My program is on OneDrive. I read somewhere that a junkapp could be the cause. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: In what way is "d.docs.live.net" added? Is it added as a part of a URL, or as an extra URL, or something else?

Comment: You are naming some junk apps (like: "Cortana", "OneDrive", "Office365") . But, more seriously, you are avoiding the real description when it comes to the problem. Where did you read (an why do you believe that info?) that some junk app is the cause of this issue?

Comment: Luuk : we found the information about the junk app via the Microsoft community forum. They gave 6 solutions but none of them works. They suggest a.o. to use Cortana, but Cortana doesn't work in our region. I quote : "this can be due to a conflict with credentials that are stored in your device. To fix your concern with the pop-up window, we'd recoçmmend performing the following" , and then they suggest Cortana. we ourselves did not add the "d.docs.live", it just pops up after the "fiche.pdf".

Comment: Andrew Morton : "d.docs.live." is not added, it just pops up after the name "fiche.pdf".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but we finally found the problem : in the name of the attachment there was a space too many, so the system did not recognize the attachment.
We apologize for any inconvenience.